# Cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Rectangle'

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I have 2 classes :

Forme.h

```
class Forme
{
private:
    string _nom;

protected:
    Forme(string nom){nom = _nom;}
    ~Forme();


    virtual string ToString()const = 0;
};
```

Rectangle.h

```
class Rectangle : public Forme
{
private :
    int _x;
    int _y;
    unsigned int _largeur;
    unsigned int _hauteur;
public :
    Rectangle() : _x(0) , _y(0) , _largeur(0) , _hauteur(0) , Forme("") {};
    Rectangle(int x, int y, int largeur, int hauteur, string nom): _x(x) , _y(y) , _largeur(largeur) , _hauteur(hauteur) , Forme(nom) {}
    Rectangle(const Rectangle& rectangle) : Forme(""){/*nothing wroten yet */};
    virtual ~Rectangle() {}


    virtual string toString() const {return "test";}
};
```

main.cpp :

```
Rectangle* r = new Rectangle(0,0,5,5,"test");
```

But when I compile this code, I get this Error :

> main.cpp | error: cannot allocate an object of abstract type 'Rectangle'

Can someone explain me why I get this error? I don't know why I get this error because toString() is defined in Rectangle.h, I didn't wrote anything in Rectangle.cpp and Forme.cpp.

Thank you.

(Sorry for my bad English level, I'm French)

Comment: You don't need or want `new` to have a rectangle. Just `Rectangle r(0,0,5,5"test");`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a typo:

base class

```
class Forme
{
    virtual string ToString()const = 0;
};
```

derived class

```
class Rectangle : public Forme {
    virtual string toString() const {return "test";}
}
```

Also:

```
~Forme();
```

this has no definition. Fix it with `{}` and possibly mark it as virtual.

Comment: And in C++11, writing `string toString() const override` would spot the typo.

Comment: Actually, the destructor *can* be pure virtual too, as long as it has a definition. There's no point in making it so in this case though.

Comment: @user2079303 If I'm not mistaken "A pure virtual function or pure virtual method is a virtual function that is required to be implemented by a derived class that is not abstract"

Comment: @MarcoA, generally yes, except a pure virtual destructor is different. The derived class doesn't need to implement it's parent's pure virtual destructor; the parent must implement it itself. A pure virtual function also makes the base class abstract which is what pure virtual destructors are used for: making the base class abstract. In this case the base class is already abstract because it has another pure virtual method, so making the destructor pure virtual doesn't add anything useful. But it wouldn't cause UB either.

Comment: I just found this and played around with it: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/11/13/pure-virtual-destructors-in-c/

I'll be honest: I didn't know of it. Thanks for pointing that out to me!

Comment: My pleasure :) I learned it on stackoverflow as well.